# How to bind the same prefix with multiple properties class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Assume that there is a yaml configuration:

```
foo:
  a:
  b:
  c:
  d:
```

Generally, you will create an object like this:

```
@Data
@Validated
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooProperties {
    @NotBlank
    private String a;
    // b c and d
}
```

But for the consideration of the project structure, I need to divide them into multiple objects in different packages, And they will use the same prefix.

package one:

```
@Data
@Validated
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class AProperties {
    // only a property
    @NotBlank
    private String a;
}
```

package two:

```
@Data
@Validated
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class BProperties {
    // only b property
    @NotBlank
    private String b;
}
```

...

And now, when my project fetch config from config server, Spring will say:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Binding to target [Bindable@2b32cd10 type = AProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix=foo, value=foo), @org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated(value={})]] failed:

Property: foo.b
Value: someValue
Origin: "foo.b" from property source "bootstrapProperties-xxx"
Reason: The elements [foo.b] were left unbound.
```

So, How can I bind the same prefix with multiple properties class? Thx~

Comment: Well If i'm not mistaken you are using it correctly. But you have to provide fields for all values within that section of your configuration. As it states, AProperties is missing b. But maybe, when setting `ignoreUnknownFields=true` in the configuration annotation it could work.

Comment: @phaen Oh nice, I habitually add `IgnoreunkNownFields = FALSE` on every properties class, everything is working fine now. thx again~

Comment: There is an enhancement scheduled for boot 2.6 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26144